# convert CSV file to nested JSON and insert in to mongodb using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a CSV file named data.csv. I want to convert this flat CSV file in to nested JSON and insert it in to mongodb using python.Below is the code which i have used to convert CSV to nested JSON, but i am not able to insert it in to mongodb. it shows error.Can somebody help?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

try: 
    conn = MongoClient() 
    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB") 

# database 
db = conn.database
collection = db.collection2 

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\swetha1\Desktop\data.csv')

def get_nested_rec(key, grp):
    rec = {}
    rec['PrimaryId'] = key[0]
    rec['FirstName'] = key[1]
    rec['LastName'] = key[2]
    rec['City'] = key[3]

    for field in ['CarName','DogName']:
        rec[field] = list(grp[field].unique())

    return rec

records = []
for key, grp in df.groupby(['PrimaryId','FirstName','LastName','City']):
    rec = get_nested_rec(key, grp)
    records.append(rec)

records = dict(data = records)

r=json.dumps(records,default=int,indent=4)
print(r)
collection.insert(r)
print("inserted")
```

output converting CSV to nested JSON is as follows:

```
Connected successfully!!!
{
    "data": [
        {
            "PrimaryId": 100,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "City": "NewYork",
            "CarName": [
                "Toyota",
                "BMW"
            ],
            "DogName": [
                "Spike",
                "Rusty"
            ]
        },
        {
            "PrimaryId": 101,
            "FirstName": "Ben",
            "LastName": "Swan",
            "City": "Sydney",
            "CarName": [
                "Volkswagen",
                "Ford",
                "Audi"
            ],
            "DogName": [
                "Buddy",
                "Max"
            ]
        },
    {
        "PrimaryId": 102,
        "FirstName": "Julia",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "City": "London",
        "CarName": [
            "Mini"
        ],
        "DogName": [
            "Lucy"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

but shows following error while inserting in to JSON:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 38, in <module>
    collection.insert(r)
  File "C:\Users\swetha1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", 
line 3161, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "C:\Users\swetha1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", 
line 639, in _insert
    blk.ops = [(message._INSERT, doc) for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\swetha1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", 
line 639, in <listcomp>
    blk.ops = [(message._INSERT, doc) for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\swetha1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", 
line 623, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
 TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

referred few links too but cudnt understand how to insert.

data.CSV

```
PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of pymongo (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) you should insert `document` which **must be** a mutable mapping type that is not string returned by `json.dumps()` but dictionary you have to create from the data.

Also documentation says to use `insert_one()` or `insert_many()` since `insert()` deprecated (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert).